# Is there a way to insert list of json/maps in cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cql

I am trying to insert a list of json in cassandra. I have made a column named medias but can't figure out how to insert the medias in this column. I tried using a UDT but doesn't seem to be working. But the maps have dynamic datatypes. Here is a sample:

[
{
"id": "0c2ed74f-6937-490e-9385-6b1feb16e0bd",
"name": "000009A.mp4",
"mediaType": 1,
"contentSize": 0,
"width": "480.0",
"height": "480.0",
"author": "ae89d4c5-6912-43c7-a6ee-6f740baef818",
"created_at": "2020-08-02T11:12:59Z"
}
]

Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this? Any help would be great.

**EDIT**
This is how I have defined my table

```
CREATE TABLE post(
        id text, 
        title text,
        content text,
        author text,
        created_at text,
        updated_at text,
        medias list<frozen<media>>
        PRIMARY KEY(id,author)
);
```

And the UDT I defined is:

```
CREATE TYPE media(
        id text,
        name text,
        mediaType int,
        contentSize int,
        width text,
        height text,
        author text,
        created_at text
                );
```

Comment: What is the column definition for this column? The table schema would be useful.

Comment: Agree that it would be good to know your schema. Are you aware of the JSON keyword for INSERTs and SELECT?

By "maps have dynamic datatypes" do you mean that the fields are indeterminate? Is there a known set of fields that could be modeled as a row?

Comment: @AdamHolmberg yes I know all the fields there can be and their types. By "maps have dynamic datatypes" I meant that the types are not all text types. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known list of columns, you can insert JSON directly.  Any columns not  present will have a NULL value.  Cassandra is very efficient at managing sparse tables.

```
CREATE TABLE post(
    id text,
    title text,
    content text,
    author text,
    created_at text,
    updated_at text,
    name text,
    mediaType int,
    contentSize int,
    width text,
    height text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,author)
);

INSERT INTO post JSON '{ 
    "id": "0c2ed74f-6937-490e-9385-6b1feb16e0bd", 
    "name": "000009A.mp4", 
    "mediaType": 1, 
    "contentSize": 0, 
    "width": "480.0", 
    "height": "480.0", 
    "author": "ae89d4c5-6912-43c7-a6ee-6f740baef818", 
    "created_at": "2020-08-02T11:12:59Z"
}';
```

See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html

Comment: Brad Schoening thanks, but  this much data I can still add but can't figure out how should i structure the Post model for medias column to get the array of medias while fetching a row .

Comment: @KanavAnand. Ok, it seems you want 'media' to be a separate entry from the base table.  Could explain why that is preferred over having columns in the base table for media values?  What is the relationship between 'post' and 'media' -- can the same media list be used in more than one post?

Comment: it is not necessary to have media as a separate entity. I am using cassandra for read only and  I want to save media as an array of json so I don't have to query another table for fetching medias. For your question, one post can have many medias and no same media object cannot be used in another post. Should I change the structure of tables or what? Can't seem to get my head around this.

Comment: @KanavAnand Could you 1) describe what the 'post' table contains and 2) provide an example of your read query?  It's fine to de-normalize your data in Cassandra, so that your schema includes both transactional data about say when a media type was streamed, and de-normalized columns for the media content information.